# What is the purpose of kotlin contract

Tags: android, kotlin

Was reading the apply function code source and found

```
contract {
        callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    }
```

and contract has an empty body, experimental

```
@ContractsDsl
@ExperimentalContracts
@InlineOnly
@SinceKotlin("1.3")
@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")
public inline fun contract(builder: ContractBuilder.() -> Unit) { }
```

what is the real purpose of ***contract*** and is it here to stay in the next versions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is the real purpose of contract

The real purpose of Kotlin **contracts** is to help the compiler to make some assumptions which can't be made by itself. Sometimes the developer knows more than the compiler about the usage of a certain feature and that particular usage can be taught to the compiler.

I'll make an example with `callsInPlace` since you mentioned it.

Imagine to have the following function:

```kotlin
fun executeOnce(block: () -> Unit) {
  block()
}
```

And invoke it in this way:

```kotlin
fun caller() {
  val value: String 
  executeOnce {
      // It doesn't compile since the compiler doesn't know that the lambda 
      // will be executed once and the reassignment of a val is forbidden.
      value = "dummy-string"
  }
}
```

Here Kotlin **contracts** come in help. You can use `callsInPlace` to teach the compiler about how many times that lambda will be invoked.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalContracts::class)
fun executeOnce(block: ()-> Unit) {
    contract {
        callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    }
    block()
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalContracts::class)
fun caller() {
  val value: String 
  executeOnce {
      // Compiles since the val will be assigned once.
      value = "dummy-string"
  }
}
```

> is it here to stay in the next versions?

Who knows. They are still experimental after one year, which is normal for a major feature. You can't be 100% sure they will be out of experimental, but since they are useful and they are here since one year, in my opinion, likely they'll go out of experimental.

Comment: Thanks just found this useful Article about contracts https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/understanding-kotlin-contracts-f255ded41ef2